# Qt Custom Slots

Tags: c++, qt, slider, signals-slots, qt-signals

Why doesn't the slot Reset() work? I want the button "reset" to reset the value of the sider to zero.

```
class MySlider : public QSlider
{
   public:
    MySlider(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = 0) : QSlider(orientation parent){}

   public slots:
   void Reset()
   {
   this->setValue(0);
   }
};

//it doesnt work when i try this

MySlider * Slider = new MySlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);

QPushButton *Reset = new QPushButton(tr("Reset"), this);

connect(Reset, SIGNAL(clicked()), Slider, SLOT(Reset()) );
```

Comment: what does connect return? It should return true if the slot was setup correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `Q_OBJECT` to the private section of the class. This will cause `moc` to create the meta-data necessary for signals and slots to work. See http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

Comment: I tried Q_GADGET (becuase i need it to be a QSlider subclass) and it didn't work

Comment: Wow, I hadn't encountered Q_GADGET before, I actually had to go look that up :) QSlider is a QObject and so is your subclass of QSlider so use Q_OBJECT.

Comment: @ArnoldSpence  When I tried QObject in the private section of the class I got this error: undefined reference to 'vtable for MySlider'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error fixes this error

Comment: @Geore: `QSlider` is a descendant of `QObject`, so `Q_OBJECT` is the correct choice, not `Q_GADGET`