# linker error: undefined reference to `vtable of QGLViewer’

Tags: c++, gcc, qt4, linker-errors

I'm working on a visualization project. It should view a 3d model on a QGLViewer. I have a subclass of QGLViewer defined like this:

```
class GLViewer : public QGLViewer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLViewer(QWidget *parent = 0,const QGLWidget* shareWidget=0, Qt::WFlags flags=0);
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void paintGL();
signals:
public slots:
};
```

Implementing the c’tor like this:

```
GLViewer::GLViewer(QWidget *parent, const QGLWidget* shareWidget, Qt::WFlags flags):
    QGLViewer(parent,shareWidget,flags)
{
}
```

I’m getting linker error:

```
glviewer.o: In function `GLViewer::GLViewer(QWidget*, QGLWidget const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)':
glviewer.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `vtable for GLViewer'
glviewer.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `vtable for GLViewer'
```

**EDIT:**
This is content of `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui opengl xml

TARGET = qglviewer-test
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lqglviewer-qt4 -lGLU -lGLEW

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        glviewer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        glviewer.cpp
```

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

Comment: Can you post implementation of all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not running glviewer.h through moc. That's what the error is saying. In your .pro file, change

```
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        glviewer.cpp
```

to

```
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        glviewer.h               <------
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post full implementation of your GLViewer class (only the constructor), but the reason to get this error:

```
undefined reference to `vtable for GLViewer'
```

is that you didn't implement some virtual functions (I assume either `initializeGL()`, `resizeGL(int width, int height)` or `paintGL()`).

Comment: @sorush-r: Are you sure you've implemented all of them? Perhaps you forgot to put `GLViewer::` in one of the the definitions?

Answer (score 1):

As VJovic said, this kind of problem is usually caused by an unimplemented virtual function. I noticed that there is no declaration/definition of `GLViewer` destructor. Is the destructor of `QGLViewer` is a `virtual` function? If this is the case, try to provide a destructor for `GLViewer` class, this may solve your problem.

Comment: but the default destructor of the `GLViewer` class will be virtual, no?

Comment: @VJovic If the destructor of OGLViewer is declared as virtual, ~GLViewer is virtual. Otherwise not.

Comment: @sorush-r I guess there is some problem with the Marco Q_OBJECT. Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error, hope it is useful to you.

Comment: @LeiMou dtor of `QGLWidget` is declared as virtual.