# Adding signal to custom Qthread

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals

I´m trying to add a signal to my qthread, but I get an some errors:

error: undefined reference to `vtable for RFDongleCommunication'

error: undefined reference to `RFDongleCommunication::newLogger(unsigned char, unsigned char)'

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef RFDONGLECOMMUNICATION_H
#define RFDONGLECOMMUNICATION_H
#include <QThread>
#include "qextserialport.h"
#include <QtGui>

class RFDongleCommunication: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit RFDongleCommunication(QextSerialPort * port);

    QextSerialPort * rfport;
    QByteArray data;

signals:

    void newLogger(uchar,uchar);

private:

    void run();

};

#endif // RFDONGLECOMMUNICATION_H
```

And the cpp file

```
#include "rfdonglecommunication.h"
#include "QDebug"

RFDongleCommunication::RFDongleCommunication(QextSerialPort * port)
{
    rfport=port;
}

void RFDongleCommunication::run()
{
    while(!(rfport->bytesAvailable()));
    data = rfport->readAll();

    uchar id = data[1];
    uchar type = data[2];
    emit newLogger(id,type); 
}
```

Does anybody see what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your header is being moc'ed?

Comment: Nope, because I have no idea what that is...

Comment: I think you should add    " #include <Object.h> " and try

Comment: How are you building your source? Qt contains a special preprocessor that takes the header files with `Q_OBJECT` definitions and processes signal/slot and other QT relevant info, before source is being compiled. If that does not happen, C++ won't be able to process the result.

Comment: I use the build-button in the bottom left corner of Qt to build my project (MinGW (QtSDK) Debug)

Comment: clean all and retry the compilation. Btw there are several posts with an answer to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqt%5Dundefined+reference+to+%60vtable+

Comment: possible duplicate of [Q\_OBJECT throwing 'undefined reference to vtable' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error)

Comment: So I assume you are using QT creator. Can you try to do `Rebuild` ?

Comment: first pushing qmake solved my problem... Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your class is in a different .cpp and .h file that are included in the MOC process generation

> Click on: File - New File or Project - Files and classes - C++ - New
>   class

**undefined reference to `vtable** means that the moc cpp file is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a very old post, but it seems people still keep asking very similar or even exactly the same question. I would elaborate the answer given by Rudolfs Bundulis above a little, and hope it would be helpful.

In case you are using Qt Creator and when you compiled your project for the first time, you did not put "Q_OBJECT" in your header file, then the moc cpp file for your (qthread) cpp file was not generated. In this case, simply running "Clean All" and "Rebuild All" after putting "Q_OBJECT" in your header file will not work. You need to go to your build folder to manually delete the Qt generated "Makefile" and run "Rebuild All" or "Build All" again, your error message will be gone.