# Undefined reference to `vtable for QMySQLDriverPlugin` when building QMYSQL for Qt 5.0.1 32bit on Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I want to compile the `QMYSQL driver for Qt 5.0.1 32bit` on Windows.
After obtaining the .a and .h files for MySQL, I added them to `Qt\5.0.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql\mysql.pro` with `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS`.

However, when compiling, both in release and debug mode, I get the following error:

```
mysql\.obj\debug_shared\main.o:-1: In function `ZN18QMYSQLDriverPluginC2Ev': 
mysql\main.cpp:60: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QMYSQLDriverPlugin'
```

I already tried to ask on the #qt IRC channel but it seems like nobody knows the answer to my problem.

Does anyone have an idea about how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by following the 3 steps of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774659/2205245).
I had to create a .cpp and .h file to put the definition and implementation of QMYSQLDriverPlugin which was originally in main.cpp.