# What's the difference between <CLASS>.moc and moc_<CLASS>.cpp

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake, moc

Most of my classes generate a `moc_<CLASS>.cpp` file. Why do some classes generate a `<CLASS>.moc` file instead of/as well as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<CLASS>.moc` is generated wherever there is a need to `MOC` the source file as well as/instead of the header (i.e. if the `Q_OBJECT` macro is used in the source).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774660/969305) for how this can be achieved.