# QObject::connect: No such signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I need to know what am I doing wrong.

I tried researching about it but I can't really find anything that it's related to my case. I am new to QT and debugging signal and slots is kinda technical for me.

What I wanted to do is just simple: make a thread that will continuously send signal to my `QProgressBar` widget.

Here's my essential code snippets:

**thread.h**

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{

public:
    MyThread(QWidget * parent = 0);


signals:
    void valueChanged(int value);

protected:
    void run();
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyThread * test = new MyThread(this);
    connect(test,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
    test->start();
}
```

**thread.cpp**

```
MyThread::MyThread(QWidget * parent)
{

}




void MyThread::run(){

emit valueChanged(10);  //for simplicity

}


void MyThread::valueChanged(int value){

}
```

I only have a single `progressBar` on my UI and my `main` is the same as the default.

Anyway, upon running of the code. I kept on getting this `no such signal` from my thread class. May I know what am I doing wrong?. I would also like to clarify if my understanding is right regarding `signals and slots` in my own words: it means that the `slot` will be triggered everytime the `signal` is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the error message is due to a missing `Q_OBJECT` macro at the top of your `MyThread` declaration. The documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html explains this is necessary for any class that wants to declare signals and slots.

Change your class definition to:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyThread(QWidget * parent = 0);

    signals:
        void valueChanged(int value);

    protected:
        void run();
};
```

Take a look at the linked documentation, specifically the **A Small Example** section, for a complete explanation why this is needed.

Comment: I tried this but i kept on getting the `undefined reference to vtable for MyThread`.

Comment: That message is `moc` related. I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error addresses it.

Answer (score 3):

You must not implement a signal in a .cpp file. MOC will do that and there must only be one implementation.

Just delete this part:

```
void MyThread::valueChanged(int value){

}
```

If your code works, that might be luck because the linker throws away the right implementation. You should not rely on that.