# Using connect method to connect to a slot

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building an application that requires a Qdialog, and a few buttons.

I am attempting to use the Command behavioural design pattern in my implementation. My project so far has 4 classes. (Please excuse the rough UML)

```
Command
+execute()

zoomInAndOut : Command
+execute()

MenuItem
-QPushButton
-command
+clicked()

Dialog
```

So within the dialog class, I create a menuItem (which has a QPushButton and Command member variable), and what I need to happen is that when the menuItems button has been clicked, it calls the menuItems "clicked" method (which in turn calls the commands execute method). I know that the "connect" function must be used, however after many, many attempts, I cannot get it to work correctly.

Within Dialog the code roughly looks like this

```
zoomInAndOut zoomCommand;
menuItem *zoom = new menuItem(new QPushButton("Zoom", this), QRect(QPoint(300, 0), QSize(100, 50)), &zoomCommand);
connect(zoom->getButton(), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(zoom->clicked()));
```

As mentioned before the connect method is completely wrong, but you can see what I am attempting to achieve. How can I make this work?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What button zoom returning? Show the code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code

`connect(zoom->getButton(), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(zoom->clicked()));`

to

`connect(zoom->getButton(), SIGNAL(clicked()), zoom, SLOT(clicked()));`

Comment: Hi! When attempting this it results in the compilation error stating: "No known conversion from 'menuItem * ' to 'const QObject *' for 3rd argument.

Comment: Ok. What you returning on `getButton()` method?

Comment: Is zoom's method `clicked()` in `public slots:` section of zoom's class?

Comment: Yes, it is. I added both yours and Aarons solution. Which has now led me to this: http://imgur.com/WPVHLRY

Comment: Yes, I believe I do - however the error shown was actually irrelevant and after a clean, and fresh build the QT is now telling me that I have a forward declaration of my QPushButton...  You can see the code and error more cleanly here: http://imgur.com/u1v3lV4

Comment: Well, add `#include <QPushButton>` to class

Comment: It compiled! Thank you! I have been working on this error for the past 2-3 hours. Thank you kindly. When I click the button, the program crashes, but as long as it compiles, I should be able to take it from here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your menuItem class contains the `Q_OBJECT` macro the line after the opening `{`. And make sure the `clicked()` method is in the `slots` section of the class body.

Comment: Hi! I have never heard of doing this, but I was able to add it  after a quick google search. Which has led to the following screenshot: http://imgur.com/WPVHLRY

I'm pretty confident I added the macro correctly, however when attempting to compile I receive the compiler linker error you can see at the bottom of the screenshot.

Comment: Does it compile if you remove the macro ? (But you need it for SIGNAL and SLOTS to work within menuItem)

Comment: You should put your class declaration in the header file. Is it? O_OBJECT won't work in a cpp file. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error

Comment: Hi Aaron, a combination of yours and @someoneinthebox solution has got the program to compile. Thank you for your help!